# Getting a strange issue while building app

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

When I build the app I get the following error:

> Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build
>   tasks may have failed for unknown reasons. Some of these (up to 12)
>   may be listed below.

But it is not showing any of the 12 errors. This error is driving me mad and I could not find why I'm getting it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Umm.. what did you do since last successful build? i hope you are using version control on your project

Comment: Maybe try a clean build? If that doesn't work, then maybe check pre-/post-build actions if you have any.

Comment: I did Clean build and got clean succcedded .Again if I build i got the same error.I can see this also Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 255 as error

Comment: @xlc Can u please tell me how can I check for version control